# Perform SQL JOIN on tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

For the following query,

```
SELECT columnA
FROM XYZ JOIN XDE
ON XYZ.columnA=XDE.columnA
```

I get this error,

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'columnA'.
```

Where XYZ and XDE are the table names,

[image: Table: XYZ]

[image: Table: XDE]

Why won't it work in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define which table columnA comes from, since it exists in both tables listed in the join.  For instance:

```
SELECT XYZ.columnA
FROM XYZ JOIN XDE
ON XYZ.columnA=XDE.columnA
```

Answer (score 1):

because you're not specifying which table to select ColumnA from.

```
SELECT XYZ.columnA
FROM XYZ JOIN XDE
ON XYZ.columnA=XDE.columnA
```

Should do the trick.